# OLE DB destination run infinite

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have this procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[populate_Profesoret] 
AS
BEGIN
SELECT 
       P_id,
       Emri,
       Mbiemri,
       Ditelindja,
       Email,
       Username,
       Password,
       D_id,
       Dg_id


FROM 
      [Departamentet].[dbo].[Profesore]

WHERE 
      P_id not in(select P_id from [departamentet_DB_DW].[dbo].[DW_profesoret]);

End;
EXEC [dbo].[populate_Profesoret];
```

On the OLE DB source I run : `EXEC [dbo].[populate_Profesoret];` to get all rows of relation table. Now on the OLE DB destination I have the following:

[image]

And when I click Start then the destination run infinite

[image]

Comment: That screenshots show a problem writing to the *destination* for which you didn't provide any information. Is the table locked by another operation? Did you check Activity Monitor? Are you trying to write to the *same* table you use in your SELECT? The source and destination use different connections. Your SELECT can lock an entire table so if you use `TABLE LOCK` in the destination, you'll block yourself

Comment: In the destination i have the first screenshot that it show the mapping

Comment: the locking options are in the `Connection Manager` page, not the mappings. *Did you check Activity Monitor to see who's blocking your INSERT?*. The destination's options don't matter if another process locks the entire table

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5tjh3owm6v613k8/Capture.PNG?dl=0)

Comment: **Activity Monitor**. What is going on there? Who is blocking the BULK INSERT ?

Comment: what?i cant understand

Comment: Your screenshot shows that everything is already loaded. It shows a blocked destination. That is, a blocked BULK INSERT. You'll see what is running and what is blocked in your database from SSMS's Activity Monitor. The ID of the process that blocks your operation will appear in the same window. If it's the same as the process ID of BULK INSERT, it means your code is blocking itself. This can happen if your selection ends up locking an entire table (missing indexes perhaps?) and you try to *insert* into that table with a TABLOCK. That's just a guess though

Comment: Look i have one procedure that i have selected the Relation table rows.
then on the DW tables i have the same table with the sames columns i want only to fill the DW table with the relation rows table